# Getting data from JQUERYpost in PHP

Tags: php, jquery

My javascript:

```
$(document).on("click", "#login-submit", function() {
    var username = $('#username').val();
    var password = $('#password').val();

     $.post (
        'db/ajax/login.php',
        {username:username,password:password},
        function(data) {
            $('#login-container').html(data);
    });
});
```

My PHP:

```
if ( $_REQUEST['password'] ) {
    echo $_POST['password'];
}
```

However i am not getting anything back out in my div that the data is to be displayed to. I know Im getting values for the variables and that the on click works because i testing alerting the variables. I just cant seam to get it to the pp PHP. I know the path is correct also.

Comment: What is your `alert(data)` return?

Comment: in your browser's dev tools (inspect element in Chrome), do you see the request? What it returns?

Comment: `$.post( "db/ajax/login.php", { username:username,password:password })
  .done(function( data ) {
    alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
  });`

Comment: figured it out. For some reason it was my .htaccess page. Dont know why that would be but when i got rid of the file it worked just fine. Why would that be you think?

Answer (score 0):

// PHP

```
if ( $_REQUEST['password'] ) {
    echo $_POST['password'];
}else {
echo 1;
}
```

// JS

```
$.post (
        'db/ajax/login.php',
        {username:username,password:password},
        function(data) {
            alert(data);
            $('#login-container').html(data);
});
```

Check the alert. If alert is still not working. Please make sure you don't have any js errors in your code